# Spring Data Jpa Save Test Fails

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am really out of options here. I am trying to save an entity to the database and assert that the value has been persisted. I am using a H2 in memory database.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Every time I run my application I get a null value back.

Here are my classes:

**CarRepositoryTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest(showSql= true)
public class CarRepositoryTest
{
    @MockBean
    private CarRepository repo;

    @Test
    public  void saveTest() throws Exception {

        Car car = new Car(1L, "MyFirstCar");
        Car saved =  repo.save(car);

        assertNotNull(saved);
    }
}
```

**CarRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long>
{
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2console
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

**JpaTestApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.al.repository")
public class JpaTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using @MockBean with your repo and the default behavior which would be to return null. Given you're using h2 presumably you want a real, non-mocked, repo.

Comment: @SeanCarroll you are my savior, I am been going at it for a while. I replaced the MockBean and Autowired to create the instance and now it all works. :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please post this as an answer and accept it or delete the question? without this, it looks like this question is still needing an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was as easy as autowiring the repo and not a MockBean as suggested by @SeanCarrol

So my test looks like this now:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest(showSql= true)
public class CarRepositoryTest
{
    @Autowire
    private CarRepository repo;

    @Test
    public  void saveTest() throws Exception {

        Car car = new Car(1L, "MyFirstCar");
        Car saved =  repo.save(car);

        assertNotNull(saved);
    }
}
```